# Combine mysql results

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables

**Menu:**

```
+----+--------------+
| id |     name     |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Salad Salmon |
|  2 | Tomato Soup  |
+----+--------------+
```

**Cats:**

```
+----+--------------+
| id |    catname   |
+----+--------------+
|  1 |    Salads    |
|  2 |    soups     |
|  3 |    Fish      |
+----+--------------+
```

**Relation:**

```
+--------+-------+
| menuid | catid |
+--------+-------+
|   1    |   1   |
|   1    |   3   |
|   2    |   2   |
+--------+-------+

$menu       = "menu";
$cats       = "cats";
$relation   = "relation";


$sql = "
SELECT $menu.id mi, $menu.name, $cats.id, $cats.catname
FROM $menu
INNER JOIN $relation ON $menu.id = $relation.menuid
INNER JOIN $cats ON $cats = $relation.groupid
";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<div>'.$row[‘mi'].' '.$row['name'].' '.$row['catname'].'</div>';
}
```

The output shows this

1 / Salad Salmon / Salads

2 / Salad Salmon / Fish

3 / Tomato Soup / Soups

How can I combine the same ID and the output like this

1 / Salad Salmon / Salads, Fish

2 / Tomato Soup / Soups

Comment: Seeing as you have ready access to application code, just handle the display issues there

Comment: And see about prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL way of doing this

```
SELECT menu.name, GROUP_CONCAT(catname) 
FROM relation
JOIN menu ON menuid = menu.id 
JOIN cats ON catid = cats.id
GROUP BY menuid
```

> Read more about `group_concat` [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

If you want to do it in php,

```sql
SELECT menu.id AS mid, menu.name, catname 
FROM relation
JOIN menu ON menuid = menu.id 
JOIN cats ON catid = cats.id
```

then in php

```php
$items = [];
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if (!array_key_exists($row['mid'], $items) {
        $items[$row['mid']] = $row['name'] . " " . $menu['catname'];
    } else {
        $items[$row['mid']] .= ", " . $menu['catname'];
    }
}
```

```php
$num = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
   echo "<div>{++$num}. {$item}</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate function `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT 
    $menu.id, 
    $menu.name, 
    group_concat($cats.catname order by $cats.id separator ', ') catnames
FROM $menu
INNER JOIN $relation ON $menu.id = $relation.menuid
INNER JOIN $cats ON $cats = $relation.groupid
GROUP BY $menu.id, $menu.name
```